# PHP OCI, Oracle, and default number format

Tags: php, oracle, formatting, oracle-call-interface

When I execute a fetch from an Oracle database using PHP OCI, numbers that are less than 1 are shown as `.XXXXXX,` e.g. `.249999`. Is there a way to set this to `0.XXXXXX` or to any other format, without modifying every query to use `to_char()` explicitly? (Perhaps through some session parameters?)

Comment: There is even a "bug report" for this https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=43618

Comment: Review 'Fetching and Working With Numbers' on p 155 of [The Underground PHP and Oracle Manual](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/php/201212-ug-php-oracle-1884760.pdf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do what you're asking globally short of modifying php/oci-extension source code. The reason for this behavior is because oracle oci omits 0s in results and php converts all results from oci to strings without performing any casting depending on column datatype. Even results in SQL*Plus omit 0 by default, and SQL*Plus formatting has to be invoked with `set numformat` to customize column formatting and prepend 0s.

There is currently no alter session parameter you can set to change this behavior.

Most common way to work around this is to use a wrapper around your queries and check for numeric columns with `is_numeric` and then format the numeric column values with `number_format` or `sprintf`. Hopefully your application already uses a wrapper around stock php oci functions so you can make the change in one location.

Answer (score 2):

Using PHP you can easily add the 0, by converting to float:

```
$a = '.249999';
echo (float) $a;
```

Meaning you can convert your number by

```
$row['number'] = (float) $row['number'];
```

after fetching it from the DB.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm looking for a way to change it globally. We have many queries that would need to be changed, and this would be too much effort.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to fix decimals numbers in multiple rows, here's a function to solve it.

```
function fixDecimalNumbers(array $fetchedDataset)
{
    //workaround for Oracle driver not returning leading zero on decimal numbers between -1 and 1 -.-
    foreach($fetchedDataset as $rownum => $row){
        foreach($row as $column => $value) {
            if(substr( $value, 0, 2 ) === '-,' && is_numeric(substr( $value, 2, 1 ))){
                $row[$column] = '-0' . substr( $value, 1);
                error_log($column);
                error_log($value);
            }
            else if(substr( $value, 0, 1 ) === ',' && is_numeric(substr( $value, 1, 1 ))){
                $row[$column] = '0' . $value;
            }
        }
        $fetchedDataset[$rownum] = $row;
    }
    return $fetchedDataset;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest option
$a = '.249999';
echo ($a*1);