# Zero before comma in decimal numbers

Tags: php, oracle

I have this question about decimal numbers from oracle to php. If i have "0,7" on oracle, for example, when i use it on php, it will be ",7", without the zero.

Anyone one knows why? And a possible solution to this? Thanks!

Comment: It is about formatting. Google for "oracle number format"

Comment: Possibly duplicated post. I bet the answer is here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4284571/php-oci-oracle-and-default-number-format)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind doing this for each query, the fastest way would be converting the string to float:

```
$num = .141592653589793;
echo (float)$num;        // prints 0.141592653589793
```

Comment: This can introduce important rounding bugs. For instance, try it with `0.034220`

Answer (score 0):

Whilst I'm not familiar with Oracle, you can re add those zeros with something like this:

```
function maybe_prefix_zero($input) {
    if( substr($input, 0, 1) === ',' ) return '0' . $input;
        else return $input;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best solution that I found is to add zero to number:

```
$nbr=0.3;
echo $nbr + 0;
```

Comment: `0.3` is not the same as `0,3`